# Yii how to search for models (populate activedataprovider) with query result?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I use a search symptoms form and I pass off the symptomCode to my diseaseController

both symptoms and diseases have model classes, but the table connecting the 2 does not.

I use this query to find all the diseases that have the specific symptom

```
           $diseaseCodes = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select ('ICD10')
                    ->from('tbl_disease')
                    ->join('tbl_symptom_disease', 'tbl_disease.ICD10=tbl_symptom_disease.diseaseCode')
                    ->where('symptomCode=:symptomCode', 
                            array(':symptomCode'=>$_GET['symptomCode']))
                    ->queryAll();
```

Now I want to know how I can use this to populate a dataprovider to populate a gridview

One idea I had was to create a custom model function

```
public function queryResultSearch($diseaseArray)
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('ICD10',$diseaseArray,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

And use this to render yii's admin action (for disease models), but I can't get it to work because probably my entire way at going at this is wrong.

Can someone help me please? How to use a mysql query result to populate an activedataprovider object.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller action you can try this:

```
    $model=new ModelName('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();

    if(isset($_GET['ModelName']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['ModelName'];

   $diseaseCodes = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select ('ICD10')
        ->from('tbl_disease')
        ->join('tbl_symptom_disease', 'tbl_disease.ICD10=tbl_symptom_disease.diseaseCode')
        ->where('symptomCode=:symptomCode', 
                array(':symptomCode'=>$_GET['symptomCode']))
        ->queryAll();

    $diseaseArray=array();
    foreach ($diseaseCodes as $dc) {
        $diseaseArray[]=$dc['ICD10'];
    }

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('ICD10',$diseaseArray,true);

    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($model),array('criteria'=>$criteria));
    $dataProvider->criteria->mergeWith($model->search()->criteria);
    $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
            'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
             ));
```

Comment: thanks it worked :). Just one note: you forgot some useless code (probably from a copy pasted): "return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));"     and I have one more question, why should I use "get_class($model)" instead of the class name directly?

Comment: i have delete the return :D ... from copy/paste.... the get_class i use because you need to send object to CActiveDataProvider as first parameter and in your code you use $this because your function was write inside model(class) and not need to use get_class

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use [CArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider). This is less than ideal.. and you will have to implement all your sorting and pagination on your own

You are much better off using  a model and implementing  similar to

```
public function queryResultSearch($diseaseArray)
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('ICD10',$diseaseArray,true);
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
 }
```

To make your first model I would personally use Gii.

Comment: using a model for the interim table you mean? I have a Symptoms model with 'symptomDiseases' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SymptomDisease', 'symptomCode'), relation and a Disease model with 'symptomDiseases' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SymptomDisease', 'diseaseCode') relation. The interim table (tbl_symptom_disease) doesn't have a model (all models made with gii of course)